# How to get a youtube video stream

Tags: youtube-api

I am exprimenting with the Youtube Api and I'm trying to manipulate the videos. I mainly would like to get the video stream to apply a custom transform to it and either play it on the Youtube Player itself or on a custom one. This last point isn't important as for now, my main concern would be getting the internal stream that the player uses when you give it a video id.

Thank you for your answers/suggestions.

Edit: 
When I say "video stream", I'm not talking about the liveStream, but the regular one that you get from youtube to your phone when you play any video.

Comment: Hey'Youssef did you figure out how to get a video's playable url from youtube via their API? I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check on this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). The Live Streaming API is actually comprised of components of the YouTube Data API and the YouTube Content ID API. The [Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) enables YouTube users to manage their YouTube accounts, while the YouTube [Content ID API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/) enables interactions with YouTube's rights management system. However, all of the resources that make up the Live Streaming API are used only to create and manage live events.

A [`liveStream`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams) resource contains information about the video stream that you are transmitting to YouTube. The stream provides the content that will be broadcast to YouTube users. Once created, a `liveStream` resource can be bound to one or more [`liveBroadcast`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts.html) resources.

Here are some [examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/) for the YouTube Live Streaming API (v3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I was talking about the video stream I didn't mean the liveStream part of it, just the regular video stream that you receive when you play any video on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK YouTube (unfortunately) does not provide regular video streaming URLs. I would believe it's due to copyright and other legal issues. However, web scraping does exist and it would allow you to get the internal streaming URL (an example of a library that does this is [ytdl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)).

Note that so far, web scraping is a bit of a grey area when it comes to legality and doing so would be at your own risk.